# Auto-Playing Keynote presentation file

Tags: keynote

I've seen that on Microsoft PowerPoint, you can see the file as .ppt, which is a standard powerpoint file, and .pps, which will open straight into the presentation. Is there n equivalent of this in Keynote, be it a file extension or just a setting?

Note that I don't mean export a keynote as powerpoint, then change it to .pps, as this will remove parts of the presentation, like some animations. I mean a conversion that will keep it as is, just open straight as the presentation.